# После выравнивания apk требуется подпись

Tags: декомпиляция

После декомпиляции, сборки обратно, подписи и выравнивания с помощью zipalign.
Командой **zipalign -v 4 {APP}.apk {ZIPALIGNED_APP}.apk** появляется ошибка **INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES** это ошибка свидетельствует о том, что apk не подписан, но перед выравниванием apk файл подписывался.

apk не запускается на 11 андройде, но без проблем запускается на 10,9,8

Comment: думаю, что после выравнивания, содержимое apk немного меняется и подпись стает недействительной. Я бы вначале выравнивал, и только потом, подписывал.

Comment: Очень важный момент заключается в том, что выравнивание должно выполняться после подписания — в противном случае подписание может снова сдвинуть данные с границ 4 байтов.